# Docker Image - microsoft-dotnet-aspnet and microsoft-dotnet-runtime not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Any one have any news regarding those two images?

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime

Our services stopped working after redeploying, and those images doesn't exists anymore in docker hub

Comment: We migrated our services to newer versions, that shouldn't be a problem in most projects. Most of the libraries are compatible and I don't recall making any code changes to migrate them

Answer (score 0):

Since May 2018, Microsoft container images are being hosted in Microsoft Container registry.

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

You can find more information about official .NET Docker images [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images)

Comment: I'm using the image like `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base`  but when our application starts we get the following message: 

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version. The Framewok 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.

Comment: Hi @Vinicius Andrade, this kind of error is usually no matching runtime, if you have installed the 3.1 version of the runtime, it may be because some Nuget packages you use depend on other versions of the runtime, you need to update these packages.